# Regex negative range algorithm

Tags: regex, algorithm

I need to implement positive and negative ranges in my regex matcher.

It looks not difficult for positive range:

```
[1-3] == (1|2|3)
```

But I do not understand how to convert negative range [^1-3] to simple regex string.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

---

Update

Not. Seems it is impossible.

Ok, how regex libraries process negative ranges in this case?

Comment: Well, the problem does not related to language. One can test regex in many open libraries and web services. And negative range works where. I need to know how it works.

Comment: I misunderstood what you were talking about and deleted my comment. .Net lets you do character class subtraction.

Comment: Possibly, with lookahead/lookbehind assertions. It depends on which regexp engine you use, thus the language you use, and what you're trying to match exactly.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Are you trying to implement a regex engine?

Comment: >>  Are you trying to implement a regex engine? 
Yes

Comment: What tools are you using?

Comment: >> What tools are you using? No tools. My own implementations of Thompson algorithm with | , * , + , ? , {n,m}, () support

Answer (score 1):

If the regex engine you're using supports negative lookahead, you can do it like this:

```
(?!1|2|3).
```

`?!` is the negative lookahead operator. It says "the characters that follow this expression must not match this expression." It makes a negative match without advancing the cursor. Here it's followed by a `.` to indicate any character.

Comment: This is not what OP is asking for IMO. He wants to know how to represent negated values of edges in NFAs.